# Entity Framework equivalent of multiple joins?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am not actually sure if this is a case for inheritance or something else entirely.  I have a set of 3 tables that exist in my database. GeoSales, CountryRef & RegionRef. [EF Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz3YT.png) The GeoSales Table has a CountryID which is a foreign key to the CountryRef Table.  The Countryref Table has a regionID , which is a foreign key to the Regionref table. Every GeoSale has a CountryID, and every Countryref has a RegionID. There is also a Location table that has a foreign key of locationID to the Geosales Table

In this case, I would like to make it possible to display the RegionName field in my  application.  I am primarily a SQL developer, so I am not very strong in c# and the vast majority of the tutorials I see are for a code first approach, and have a bunch of C# code that I don't really understand.  Within Sql, I would just use 2 joins like this:

```
SELECT * FROM GeoSales G 
JOIN CountryRef C ON C.CountryId = G.CountryID 
JOIN RegionRef R ON R.RegionID = C.RegionID
JOIN Location L ON L.LocationdiD = G.LocationID
```

Within my MVC/EF Project,  how Would I create this relationship in such a way that Views can include the Region information with the GeoSales Record?

One of the things that I have considered was adding an FK to the regionref table to the GeoSales Table in addition to the countryref table, but I am not sure if that would result in the behavior I am looking for.  There can be 1 region & 1 country on a Geosale record, and there can be many countries in a region, and many geosales in a country. 
This is my class for the GeoSales

```
public partial class GeoSale
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Year { get; set; }

    public virtual CountryRef CountryRef { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

}
}
```

And This is my class for CountryRef

```
 public partial class CountryRef
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public CountryRef()
        {
            this.GeoSales = new HashSet<GeoSale>();
        }

        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RegionID { get; set; }

        public virtual RegionRef RegionRef { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<GeoSale> GeoSales { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need *joins*? EF and any ORM uses *relations* between entities to generate the appropriate queries. Create relations and navigation properties in your DbContext and entities. If you want to load all sales with country, regions etc all you need to do is write `dbContext.Sales.ToArray()` or `dbContext.Sales.Where(sale=>sale.Country.ISOCode='UK').ToArray()`. The countries, locations etc will be loaded lazily when accessed.

Comment: So do I create this in the GeoSale.cs file under the model.tt?

Comment: If you used EF Designer the *entities* should already have the relations and properties. Post your classes, not the screenshots. Your `GeoSale` class probably contains a `CountryRef` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more optimal way to do it. EF has relations and it can both lazy load and eager load. So if you are sure you are going to need those linked entities, you can just:

```
var x = context.GeoSales
          .Include(n => n.Country)
          .Include(n => n.Region)
          .Include(n => n.Location)
          .WhateverElseYouNeed(
```

You can also see this to learn more about linking entities together: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for inserting related tables

```
var x = context.Sales
          .Include(n => n.Country)
          .Include(n => n.Salesman)
```

If you want to add some specification for Saler you can do

```
var x = context.Sales
          .Include(n => n.Country)
          .Include(n => n.Salesman)
          .ThenInclude(t => t.Person)
```

You you have this result:

```
Saleles > Country
        > Salesman
                 > Person
```

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx